# What I have to edit in the server.xml?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

When I try to run a web application in eclipse I cannot success and it shows the following message:

"Several ports (8005, 8080, 8009) required by Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost are already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s)."

I try to remove the configuration of the running to start again and it didn't solve.

I review that there is nothing running in these ports, and I suppose is for a missundertanding, maybe changing the server.xml file resolve the problem, what can I edit from it? or what solutions could you give me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the port in the server.xml by changing the `<Connector>` element for example

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8000" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

Beside that: Did you restart your Eclipse? Did you start Tomcat outside of Eclipse (under Windows tomcat_install_dir/bin/startup.bat or .sh under Unix or started the service)? There would be an extra javaw process in your process list beside Eclipse.
In the Server view, are there already started servers?

Comment: Yes, there were extra javaw process, removing there it resolve the problem. Thanks a lot.